# Query running slow in SQL Server 2014 because of DISTINCT operation, working fine in SQL Server 2012

Tags: performance, distinct, sql-server-2014, sql-execution-plan, cardinality

Query looks something like this:

```
SELECT 
    A.Id, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN (C.TypeId in (54, 57, 58, 59) OR (ISNULL(B.count1, 0) + ISNULL(B.count3, 0) + ISNULL(B.count2, 0) > 0)) 
                           THEN D.AdrsId 
                           ELSE NULL 
                    END)) AS C1), 
   C2, C3.................................................C42 
FROM 
    A123 A 
INNER JOIN 
    E123 E on A.Id = A.ID 
INNER JOIN 
    B123 B on B.Id = A.Id AND B.IsDeleted = 0 
INNER JOIN 
    C123 C on C.Id = B.Id AND C.Isdeleted = 0 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    D123 D ON B.someId = D.someId AND D.IsDeleted = 0 AND D.xId > 0 
GROUP BY 
    A.Id
```

`C2, C3, ..., C42` are columns with `COUNT(DISTINCT)` operation like `C1`.

Compared query execution plans in 2012 and 2014, the difference is in distinct sort cost.

Comment: Can you **show** the two execution plans?

Comment: @marc_s  : Unable to add images of query execution plans because of low reputaion

Comment: @marc_s : Distinct sort cost in execution plan is more in sql server 2014 than sqlserver2012.

Comment: Put your images on e.g. tinypic.com and provide link to them!

Comment: Thanks Marc , below are the links

2012
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2rdkf0i&s=8#.VZvFbflViko

Comment: 2014
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=64m05t&s=8

Comment: Could you please post the **entire** execution plans? Just those tiny fragments don't really help much ....

Comment: http://tinypic.com/usermedia.php?uo=bbi8MiGk22NROmFFAIpj04h4l5k2TGxc#.VZvTcflViko

Does this help any way?
coz I am unable to capture the huge query execution plan in an image.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check the compatibility level of your database in SQL 2014 ? And confirm it's SQL Server 2014 (120). 2014 have a new cost estimator, if the compatibility level is not 120 it will use legacy one and this could lead to bad query plan.

http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/old-compatibility-level/

Hope this help.

Comment: Yes, compatibility level is SQL Server 2014 (120). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an extreme number of distinct operations. SQL Server is not particular good at dealing with `COUNT DISTINCT`.

Consider writing the temporary data that is the source for the distinct to a temp table. Then, create a `CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE` index on it. Then, run one distinct operation at a time on that temp table. This will likely result in very fast batch mode hash aggregations.

Comment: Then why it is running in 2012 without any issues even though it has 42 count distinct columns?

Comment: Is it running faster in 2012? You have not said that before. How much faster?

Comment: Yes it is taking 0 seconds to run the query in 2012.
Thats y i have mentioned the stmnt 
"Compared query execution plans in 2012 and 2014, the difference is in distinct sort cost."

Comment: In 2014 it is taking more than 30 mins

Comment: Then we should find a plan difference in structure. Those 4 vs. 5% costs certainly do not explain a difference of 1000x! They probably are just different because something else in the plan has changed the total cost. Post the full plan somewhere.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/usermedia.php?uo=bbi8MiGk22NROmFFAIpj04h4l5k2TGxc#.VZvTcflViko

Does this help any way?
coz I am unable to capture the huge query execution plan in an image.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, above solution worked in sql server 2014. It is working fine now which was timing out before.